# Draw an arc between two points on a tkinter canvas

Tags: python, canvas, tkinter, tkinter-canvas

My problem is very simple: I have two oval which centers are (x0, y0) and (x1, y1). 
If I wanted to draw a line between them, I would simply do
create_line(x0, y0, x1, y1).

But I want to draw an arc between them. I'm struggling with the maths here. Here is the situation:

- I have these two centers: they must be part of the ellipse
- There is an infinity of ellipses going through these two points, but with tkinter, we can only draw horizontal ellipses. (right ?)

I need:

- the top-left and lower-right coordinates of the rectangle that contains the ellipse
- the start angle and the extent of the arc

I'm also thinking that maybe drawing an arc is the wrong way to go ? I could do something equivalent with a line, for which I specify a lot of points on that arc (even though it wouldn't be an actual arc)

Edit to answer Blindman:

With tkinter, you can define an arc like so:
http://infohost.nmt.edu/tcc/help/pubs/tkinter/web/create_oval.html
We don't define the ellipse per se, but only the top-left and lower-right corners coordinates of the rectangle that contains the ellipse.

How the two ovals relate to each other: they don't. You just have two oval at a random position on the canvas, and you want an arc between them.
I want the arc joining the two centers of these ovals.

Finally, here is an idea of what I want, in case the two oval have the same y coordinates:

[image: ellipse]

What I want is exactly this, for any position.

And the tkinter code:

```
import tkinter as tk

class SampleApp(tk.Tk):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        tk.Tk.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)

        self.canvas = tk.Canvas(width=400, height=400)
        self.canvas.pack(fill="both", expand=True)

        self._create_token((100, 100), "white")
        self._create_token((200, 100), "pink")

        self.canvas.create_arc(100, 100 + 10, 200, 100 - 10, extent=180, style=tk.ARC)

    def _create_token(self, coord, color):
        '''Create a token at the given coordinate in the given color'''
        (x,y) = coord
        self.canvas.create_oval(x-5, y-5, x+5, y+5, 
                                outline=color, fill=color, tags="token")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = SampleApp()
    app.mainloop()
```

Comment: I started to have a look into a solution but there are too many unknowns. I have never use python so I do not know what type of ellipse/oval they use. There is also no indication of how the two ovals relate to each other and where you want the line/curve/arc/joining thing to connect the two, there a too many possibilities for an answer. Could you provide a sketch of the problem, and give the details of what you use to define both ellipses.

Comment: I updated the post, hope it's clearer now

Comment: When start and end points of arc have same x (or y) coordinates then you could use rectangle where start and end points are the midpoints of opposite sides of the rectangle and arc has extent = 180. Just like in your example code. When start and end points of arc have different x and y coordinates then you could use rectangle where start and end points are midpoints of adjacent sides of the rectangle and arc has extent of 90.

Comment: In my example code, I use the opposite corners of the rectangle and not the midpoints of opposite sides. That being said, I don't understand how your generalization to different x/y coordinates work. Can you develop a bit ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a `start` option for creating the arc, which define where to start the drawing in giving angle. Using this and some math you can use the `create_arc`-method to draw an arc for any position:

```
import Tkinter as tk


class SampleApp(tk.Tk):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        tk.Tk.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)

        self.canvas = tk.Canvas(width=400, height=400)
        self.canvas.pack(fill="both", expand=True)

        self._create_token((100, 100), "white")
        self._create_token((200, 300), "pink")
        self._create_arc((100,100), (200, 300))

    def _create_token(self, coord, color):
        '''Create a token at the given coordinate in the given color'''
        (x,y) = coord
        self.canvas.create_oval(x-5, y-5, x+5, y+5, 
                                outline=color, fill=color, tags="token")

    def _create_arc(self, p0, p1):
        extend_x = (self._distance(p0,p1) -(p1[0]-p0[0]))/2 # extend x boundary 
        extend_y = (self._distance(p0,p1) -(p1[1]-p0[1]))/2 # extend y boundary
        startAngle = math.atan2(p0[0] - p1[0], p0[1] - p1[1]) *180 / math.pi # calculate starting angle  
        self.canvas.create_arc(p0[0]-extend_x, p0[1]-extend_y , 
                               p1[0]+extend_x, p1[1]+extend_y, 
                               extent=180, start=90+startAngle, style=tk.ARC)

        '''use this rectangle for visualisation'''
        #self.canvas.create_rectangle(p0[0]-extend_x, p0[1]-extend_y, 
        #                                p1[0]+extend_x, p1[1]+extend_y)       

    def _distance(self, p0, p1):
        '''calculate distance between 2 points'''
        return sqrt((p0[0] - p1[0])**2 + (p0[1] - p1[1])**2)   

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = SampleApp()
    app.mainloop()
```

Comment: Is there an easy way to adapt this to get a different angle ? For example, an arc which would be very close to the straigth line ? As I see it, when the angle is too small, the corners of the rectangle used to define the ellipse are exactly the centers of the two ovals.

Comment: Actually, I think I can simply take a point on the bisection of the line between the two ovals, then compute the corners of that new circle.

Answer (score 1):

Actually, I will answer my own question, since I found a better way to do it.
VRage's answer is fine but it's hard to adapt in case you want the arc closer to the line between the two points.
The right way to do it is to use a line with a third point on the perpendicular bissector of the segment, combined with the "smooth" option.

Here is an example with exactly what I wanted:

```
import tkinter as tk
import math

class SampleApp(tk.Tk):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        tk.Tk.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)

        self.canvas = tk.Canvas(width=400, height=400)
        self.canvas.pack(fill="both", expand=True)

    def _create_token(self, coord, color):
        '''Create a token at the given coordinate in the given color'''
        (x,y) = coord
        self.canvas.create_oval(x-5, y-5, x+5, y+5, 
                                outline=color, fill=color, tags="token")

    def create(self, xA, yA, xB, yB, d=10):
        self._create_token((xA, yA), "white")
        self._create_token((xB, yB), "pink")

        t = math.atan2(yB - yA, xB - xA)
        xC = (xA + xB)/2 + d * math.sin(t)
        yC = (yA + yB)/2 - d * math.cos(t)
        xD = (xA + xB)/2 - d * math.sin(t)
        yD = (yA + yB)/2 + d * math.cos(t)

        self.canvas.create_line((xA, yA), (xC, yC), (xB, yB), smooth=True)
        self.canvas.create_line((xA, yA), (xD, yD), (xB, yB), smooth=True, fill="red")

   if __name__ == "__main__":
        app = SampleApp()
        app.create(100, 100, 300, 250)
        app.mainloop()
```